# Using a Windows machine as an intranet server

Tags: windows-10, networking, apache-http-server, wamp

I have an internet modem/router which I use to create an intranet. One of the computers on the intranet is a Windows 10 machine using WAMP and Apache to create an HTTP server.  The router (Xfinity) does not seem to have a DNS but my Windows machine is named "iolanthe" so other clients on the intranet can address the server as "http://iolanthe/index.php." The problem is that this always goes to C:/Users/username/www.  Is there any way to get it to go to another directory, like C:/Users/username/www/foo/foo.com/index.php?

Answer (score 1):

You can [set the Apache server root directory](https://codingshower.com/what-and-where-is-the-server-root-in-apache-web-server/). Here are two ways:

- Use the command line argument `-d` to set the path when starting Apache, `httpd -d /home/my-server-home`
- In apache2.conf, add the line `ServerRoot "/home/my-server-home"`

<sub>BTW, G&S Iolanthe was rather proud - would she *want* to be a server?</sub>